# How to delete groups containing less than 3 rows of data in R?

Tags: r, rows

I'm using the dplyr package in R and have grouped my data by 3 variables (Year, Site, Brood).

I want to get rid of groups made up of less than 3 rows. For example in the following sample I would like to remove the rows for brood '2'. I have a lot of data to do this with so while I could painstakingly do it by hand it would be so helpful to automate it using R.

```
Year Site Brood Parents
1996 A    1     1  
1996 A    1     1  
1996 A    1     0  
1996 A    1     0  
1996 A    2     1      
1996 A    2     0  
1996 A    3     1  
1996 A    3     1  
1996 A    3     1  
1996 A    3     0  
1996 A    3     1
```

I hope this makes sense and thank you very much in advance for your help! I'm new to R and stackoverflow so apologies if the way I've worded this question isn't very good! Let me know if I need to provide any other information.

Comment: Is dplyr necessary? Or are solutions in base-R or data.table also appropriate?

Comment: @Heroka `data %>% group_by(Year, Site, Brood) %>% filter(n() >= 3)` why wouldn't you use dplyr? ;)

Comment: @Mullefa because there are other options, and I'm personally more comfortable with data.table and base-R. But I understand that preferences can vary between persons :P

Comment: @Heroka I'm sure those other methods are completely appropriate! Like I say I'm a total rookie and I've simply used dplyr more than base-R/data.table :P

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the magic `n()` function within `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data <- data.frame(Year=1996, Site="A", Brood=c(1,1,2,2,2))

my_data %>% 
  group_by(Year, Site, Brood) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 3)
```

The `n()` function gives the number of rows in the current group (or the number of rows total if there is no grouping).

Comment: This awesome answer helped me, here is the official dplyr documentation for n() if anyone else needs it since I had a bit of a hard time finding it: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/n.html

The main takeaway is that n() can be used with summarise(), mutate() and filter()

Answer (score 9):

Throwing the `data.table` approach here to join the party:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)
my_data[ , if (.N >= 3L) .SD, by = .(Year, Site, Brood)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using base R:

```
temp <- read.csv(paste(folder,"test.csv", sep=""), head=TRUE, sep=",")
matches <- aggregate(Parents ~ Year + Site + Brood, temp, FUN="length")
temp <- merge(temp, matches, by=c("Year","Site","Brood"))
temp <- temp[temp$Parents.y >= 3, c(1,2,3,4)]
```

Comment: Or in a very ugly oneliner: `dat[unlist(sapply(split(dat,list(dat$Year,dat$Site,dat$Brood)),function(x){rep(nrow(x),nrow(x))}))>3,]`